# how to insert a formgroup on the fisrt line of the form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, methods

I`m trying to insert a new line in my form, using .push method. This will include the new line at the last line of the form. I also tried to use unshift to put in the first line but this methods does not is included on the formGroup methods.

There is any way to work around this?

Take a look on my html:

```
<div class="grid-table">
<div class="thead">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" ***(click)="addBankAccountForm()***">
        <mat-icon>library_add</mat-icon>  
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="td">TABLE_NAME</div>
    <div class="td">COLUMN_NAME</div>
    <div class="td">SOURCESYS_REF</div>
    <div class="td">DEFAULT_VALUE</div>
    <div class="td">DESCRIPTION</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AbacusService } from './abacus.service'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ist-abacus-default-values',
  templateUrl: './ist-abacus-default-values.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ist-abacus-default-values.component.css']
})
export class istAbacusDefaultValuesComponent implements OnInit {
  abacus:string = "IST_ABACUS_DEFAULT_VALUES";
  bankAccountForms : FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
  abacusList = [];

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder, private abacusService: AbacusService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.abacusService.getBankAccountlist(this.abacus).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
        console.log(res)
        if(res == [])
          this.addBankAccountForm();
          else {
            (res.IstValues as [] ).forEach ((bankAccount: any) => {
              this.bankAccountForms.push(this.fb.group({
                TABLE_NAME    : [ bankAccount.TABLE_NAME,    Validators.required ],
                COLUMN_NAME   : [ bankAccount.COLUMN_NAME,   Validators.required ],
                SOURCESYS_REF : [ bankAccount.SOURCESYS_REF, Validators.required ],
                DEFAULT_VALUE : [ bankAccount.DEFAULT_VALUE, Validators.required ],
                DESCRIPTION   : [ bankAccount.DESCRIPTION,   Validators.required ],
                }));
            });
          }
        }
    );
  }

  addBankAccountForm() {
    this.bankAccountForms.push(this.fb.group({
      TABLE_NAME    : [ '', Validators.required ],
      COLUMN_NAME   : [ '', Validators.required ],
      SOURCESYS_REF : [ '', Validators.required ],
      DEFAULT_VALUE : [ '', Validators.required ],
      DESCRIPTION   : [ '', Validators.required ],
    }));
  }
}
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Your code to add the form group to the array looks ok, but I don't see a binding for the form array in your template. Can you add all of the relevant code?

Comment: It's there mate in the  (click)="addBankAccountForm()">

Comment: It insert the row, but insert in the last line (bottom). I need it be at the first line of the form

Comment: Ah. You can use `.unshift()` to add an element to the beginning of an array.

Comment: No, formControl does not include this method. I fixed with insert (0, ) method

Comment: You're right, the FormArray doesn't have upsert. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.

Instead use push( ), i used insert (0, ). This makes the row being correctly placed at the top of the form.

Comment: Try to include some lines of code so it is clear where and how he can use those methods.